# php how to get the textarea tag from my sql in a textarea in php

Tags: php

I have a code which is all working right but when the code in the database has a  it goes wrong 
code like this

```
<tr><td><b>EN Page Content : </b></td><td><textarea name="pageContent" cols="150" rows="100"><?php echo  getContentWithIndex("posts",$_GET['pageID'],"content");?></textarea></td></tr>
```

and content is like this

```
<textarea placeholder="Message*:" data-constraints='@Required @Length(min=20,max=999999)' name="SenderHRMessage"></textarea>
```

so it has the end of the `</textarea>` as an end for the first one and never display any other content in the first textarea.

Comment: can you pleas explain your problem

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to this: (I have reformatted it so that it fits on the SO post)

```
<tr>
  <td><b>EN Page Content : </b></td>
  <td>
    <textarea name="pageContent" cols="150" rows="100"><?php 
      echo htmlentities(getContentWithIndex("posts",$_GET['pageID'],"content"));
    ?></textarea>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The reason is that if you have HTML code that you want to display as HTML code you need to encode it to text.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: @MBaas adding the `nl2br()` will break it again. `textarea`'s do not require them and use `\n` for new lines.

Comment: Oppps, sry for the false remark and tx for the quick clarification :)